# Generating an incrementing id based on a pattern

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Let's say I have 2 inputs: `Length` and `Outcome`.

My form has these 2 inputs with `Short` and `Long` as values for `Length` and `Success` and `Failure` for `Outcome`.

I want to generate an ID that follows this pattern `{Length}{Outcome}{auto-increment-int-padded-to-5-digits}`

Example:

```
SF00001
SF00002
LF00001
LS00001
LF00002
```

Currently, I am generating this ID like this:

```
private string NewId(string length, string outcome)
{
    string id = length + outcome;
    var maxRecordId = _context.JobRecords.Select(jr => jr.JobId).Where(jobId => jobId.Contains(id)).Max();
    if (maxRecordId == null)
    {
        return id + "00001";
    }
    else
    {
        return id + (int.Parse(maxRecordId.Substring(2)) + 1).ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
    }        
}
```

While this approach works, I am not a fan of it. With a lot of queries there is no guarantee that the generated ID is correct at the time of insertion. What is the best practice here?

Unfortunately the ID pattern is part of the specs and required.

EDIT: Misinformation: The ID Pattern is part of the requirements, but not 100% "required" to be a key. It should really read that this this Pattern needs to be a part of the table, as it is being used by other applications as part of their conventions.

Comment: This design is very problematic. You are violating 1NF by stuffing multiple values into the same tuple. The best practice here is to not do anything like this at all. You need properly normalized data with no race conditions. Then if you need a column with the data squished together like this you could create a computed column.

Comment: These kind of requests are just plain dumb. They serve no purpose and are a pain to implement. I’d sit down with the customer and give him the chance to really explain what he wants this for... give him a whole day, or a week, he’ll be unable to.

Comment: I agree with the above comments - but in what way is the generated ID not correct? Is it because you have duplicates? [edit] or just because you can't figure out how to make the string? (because it looks like you have ) in the wrong place on int.Parse)

Comment: You can create a table with columns Length, Outcome, NextID. It will have just 4 rows. When you need an id - grab corresponding NextID and increment it by 1 atomically (with for example with `UPDATE ... OUTPUT` statement). Then it will be safe against multiple concurrent id generations.

Comment: is a single sequence of number with a prefix allowed such as ... SF00001, SF00002, LF00003, LS00004, LF00005 ... if so you can just use a persisted computed column and a normal sequence ID,  Otherwise you will need a sequence per prefix combo... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql

Comment: @SeanLange Even more than that, there are issues with what happens when you get to 99999, etc. I like this approach the best, because with this, we don't technically lose any information. How would I go about creating this computed column?

Comment: @InBetween The reason is because this application triggers a job that runs another program that runs a bunch of analytics on Greenplum, which in turn gets processed by some data in mainframe. I guess it isn't required to be the ID, but it does need to be unique and identifiable. I will update the post, still a little new to this.

Comment: @mikelegg When it's generated, it's correct. But when inserting, you run into race conditions. There were a couple of syntax errors, I think i fixed them all up.

Comment: A computed column is pretty simple to create. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table or https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @SeanLange The creation of the computed column isn't what trips me up. From what I can see, computed columns can only be combined with other columns of the same row, whereas my needs are more along the lines of computing a value based off of what is existing in the table. If I have `ID`, `Length` and `Outcome` as my 3 columns, and my computed is just `{Length}{Outcome}{LeftPad(ID, 5, '0')}`, I would end up SF00001, SF00002, LF00003 instead of SF00001, SF00002, LF00001.

Comment: Well I can't see your data and have no knowledge of what you are trying to do. If you can get the 1, 2, 3 for each type or whatever those first two characters are this is pretty simple. You could use a sequence for each group.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is you run into a race condition, i.e. get duplicate keys generates, then you need to think about doing it atomically like @Evk says in his comment.

This means only allowing 1 ID to be generated at the same time.

You can do this in a couple of ways.

First the quick easy but not very future proof naive way. IFF there is only one process generating the IDs, put a static lock around your ID generating code. eg:

```
static object _lock = new object();

private string NewId(string length, string outcome)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
       // make the id
    }
}
```

This only will work if this is the only process making IDs. So if you have >1 processes, or you plan to in the future, it is not a good plan.

Second is to get the database to control the atomicity. This is the 'propper' way.

Personally I would do this is a stored procedure and not in EF.

Also, because it will lock the table you are generating the IDs from, you probably want a new table where you store only 4 rows (1 for each lenght/outcome combination) with the next ID generated in each.

You intialize the table up front to put just the 4 rows in it, with the next ID set to 0 for each one.

The stored proc depends on your DB but in pseudo code:

```
begin tran
  update id_table set next_id = next_id + 1 where lenght = the_length and success = the_success;
  select next_id from id_table  where lenght = the_length and success = the_success;
end tran
```